# Unstable Approach

Tags: approach

What is considered to be an "unstable approach"?
Which are the exact parameters against which an approach is being judged, in order to be considered "stable" or "unstable"?

Comment: Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1271/62) help?

Comment: The exact criteria varies amongst aircraft type and even from airline to airline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a stabilized approach?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/what-is-a-stabilized-approach)

Comment: For visual landings, when you gain experience and skill, the need for a "stable" approach all the way down to be able to land safely becomes somewhat less important, as long as you can get yourself configured properly in the last couple hundred feet. When you get to that "at one with the plane" level of skill, that can be fairly easy to do.